# Is there something wrong with my code to sort a array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm learning c language and I wrote a function like this to sort an array.

```
void sort(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int *i = a; i < a + n - 1; i ++)
    {
        int *j, temp, *max = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < a + n; j ++)
        {
            if (j > max)
            {
                max = j;
            }
        }
        if (*max != *i)
        {
            temp = *i;
            *i = *max;
            *max = temp;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

When I used the function to sort an array like this:

```
int arr[10] = {12, 34, 5, 689, -43, 56, -21, 0, 24, 65};
sort(arr, 10);
```

It gave the wrong answer:

```
12   34   5    689  -43  56   -21  0    24   65   
65   12   34   5    689  -43  56   -21  0    24
```

I checked the code for several times. However, I still can't find where is wrong. Could you please help me with the problem?

Comment: `if (j > max)` --> `if (*j > *max)`

Comment: Search for bubble sort!

Answer (score 4):

```
    if (j > max)
    {
        max = j;
    }
```

Here you are comparing pointers, not values, change to:

```
    if (*j > *max)
```